# De un rango de fechas obtener los días del mes por cada dos meses

Tags: php

Intento crear una función que me retorne los días del mes.

```
function devuelveArray($fechaInicio, $fechaFin, $diasFiltro){
    $arrayFechas = array();
    $fechaInicio = new DateTime($fechaInicio);
    $fechaFin = new DateTime($fechaFin);
    while($fechaInicio <= $fechaFin) {
        if ($fechaInicio->format('w'), $diasFiltro) {
            $arrayFechas[] = $fechaInicio->format('Y-m-d');
        }
        $fechaInicio->modify('+2 months'); //suma los meses
    }
    return $arrayFechas;
}

$diasFiltro = 12;//-->dia del mes
$arrayFechas=devuelveArray('2017-06-30', '2017-12-31', $diasFiltro);

foreach ($arrayFechas as  $value) {
    echo $value."<br>";
}
```

Todo esto de una rango de fechas, explico tengo la fecha inicio 2017-07-06 y la fecha fin 2017-12-31.ahora envió un parámetro que es el día 12.
Lo que busco es que una vez asignado  el parámetro 12 me liste todos los días 12 del mes, por cada 2 meses.

Finalmente el resultado que busco es:

```
2017-07-12
2017-09-12
2017-11-12
```

Comment: Tienes al parecer un error tipografico aqui: `if ($fechaInicio->format('w'), $diasFiltro)`

Comment: Podrias dejar esta linea asi: `$arrayFechas[] = $fechaInicio->format('Y-m') . "-" . $diasFiltro;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias hacer algo como esto:

```
<?php

function devuelveArray($fechaInicio, $fechaFin, $diasFiltro){

    $arrayFechas = array();

    $fechaInicio = new DateTime($fechaInicio);
    $fechaFin = new DateTime($fechaFin);

    while($fechaInicio <= $fechaFin) {
        $arrayFechas[] = $fechaInicio->format('Y-m') . "-" . $diasFiltro;
        $fechaInicio->modify('+2 months'); //suma los meses
    }

    return $arrayFechas;
}

$diasFiltro = 12;//-->dia del mes
$arrayFechas=devuelveArray('2017-06-30', '2017-12-31', $diasFiltro);

foreach ($arrayFechas as  $value) {
    echo $value."<br>";
}

?>
```

El resultado que obtendremos sera:

```
2017-06-12
2017-08-12
2017-10-12
2017-12-12
```

**Lo que hemos hecho ha sido:**

**1)** *Eliminar este condicional:*

```
if ($fechaInicio->format('w'), $diasFiltro) {
...
}
```

Ya que no contiene ninguna instruccion valida para el objetivo que buscas.

**2)** *Modificar el formato de fecha, dejandolo asi:*

```
$arrayFechas[] = $fechaInicio->format('Y-m') . "-" . $diasFiltro;
```

Lo que hacemos aqui modificar el formato de fecha para que solo imprima **año y mes**, a lo cual adjuntamos el contenido de `$diasFiltro`, que contiene el dia que estamos buscando imprimir.

Comment: Hola Ivan Botero Gracias Por Responder a mi consulta solo un dato yo ingrese la fecha de inicio 2017-06-30 esto supone que debería iniciar la lista del 2017-07-12 pero en la lista me toma 2017-06-12.como se validaría esto. Gracias